# OSHA Occupational Chemical Database

Tags: data-request, api, labor

I need to access the OSHA Occupational Chemical Database using the API. Is that service available? I would like to download it to a local database and then translate it to other languages.

Comment: is there an api? what have you even looked at or tried? the database is available for download....

Comment: Did you check http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-compliance#occupationcode

Answer (score 1):

There is an API

http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/safety-and-health

Here's an example for Chemical Exposure

https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/safety-health-chemical-exposure-inspection